# how to add css in fancy grid emptyText? trying to add custom css color on emptyText string

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, datagrid

```
tbar:[
{
  type: 'search',
  width: 300,
  emptyText: '<span id = "hello">search<span>',
  inputHeight: 30,
}]
```

I tried with id hello to change the emptyText, but could not make it, could anybody tell me how to change the opacity of seach string in emptyText

Comment: What's `tbar`?  What's "fancy grid"?  What's `emptyText`?  Please add enough info on non-standard plugins so we can recreate the issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.